How to compare specific page paths on a time series chart?
I'd like to compare several specific page paths on a time series chart in Looker Studio, similar to the Engagement > Pages and screens report in GA4:
time series chart in google analytics showing different lines for different page paths
I have created a time series chart with "year month" as the dimension and "views" as the metric and "page path" as the breakdown dimension. This shows a line in the chart for each of the top ten page paths.
How can I choose specific page paths to show here (such as "/abc" and "/123" and "/xyz"), and how can I aggregate them to include all subfolders in the path (such as "/abc/efg" and "/abc/hij" and so on)?
Please let me know if I can clarify.

I may have misunderstood and am answering a to simple question but to limit data on a chart you either add a control for the measure you want to use or add a filter


If you want to aggregate them you cam probably create a measure to do this. let me know the names of the fields you want to use and I will write one

Thank you for taking a look at this. I would like the time series chart to show a separate line representing page views for each of these folders: "/nrs", "/fpl", and "/rmrs", including any number of subfolders within each one. Having a separate line for each would let me compare page views for each of these groups of folders and subfolders at a glance.

Not a problem, can you share the structure of the relevant data and fields , ie dimension name, type and and an example of the data contained?  Also did I answer the first part of your question correctly?
